# Thymeleaf: Comma separated values of a list?

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I am beginner in Thymeleaf, I have a list and want to list elements in a line by separating comma e.g. London, Paris, Berlin, HonKong (there will be no comma after the the last element). However, the following code generate new row. So, how can I make it work as explained above?

```
<td th:each="city : ${country.cityList}">
    <td th:text="${city.name}? ${city.name} + ',' : ${city.name}"></td>
</td>
```

I know it also add an extra comma at the end of the last element and I need to use index e.g. for detecting the last index. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a sequence of `<span>` tags to hold your text.

You can use Thymeleaf's [iteration status tracking values](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#keeping-iteration-status) to know when you are handling the last item in the list.

Combining these:

```html
<td>
    <span th:each="city,iterStat : ${country.cityList}"
          th:text="${city.name} + ${!iterStat.last ? ', ' : ''}"></span>
</td>
```

The `iterStat.last` value is a boolean which tells us when we are processing the final value - and the `!` (not) operator is used to suppress the final comma + space.

---

**Update**

Based on the comment:

> *how make href links for city.name but span only for comma ?*

For something like this, you can move the `th:each` expression into a parent tag - and this is where `<th:block>` may be useful, because it does not itself generate any HTML:

```html
<th:block th:each="city,iterStat : ${country.cityList}">
    <a th:text="${city}" th:href="${city}"></a><span th:text="${!iterStat.last ? ', ' : ''}"></span>
</th:block>
```

Inside the `<th:block>...</th:block>` you can use multiple child tags to build whatever you need.

Using the above Thymeleaf, the end result could be the following HTML:

```html
<a href="São Paulo">São Paulo</a><span>, </span>
<a href="Rio de Janeiro">Rio de Janeiro</a><span>, </span>
<a href="Brasilia">Brasilia</a><span></span>
```

This generates an empty `<span></span>` at the end.

If you don't want that empty span, you can enhance the logic by using an explicit `th:if` expression:

```html
<th:block th:each="city,iterStat : ${country.cityList}">
    <a th:text="${city}" th:href="${city}"></a><span th:if="${!iterStat.last}">, </span>
</th:block>
```

Now, you will get something like this:

```html
<a href="São Paulo">São Paulo</a><span>, </span>
<a href="Rio de Janeiro">Rio de Janeiro</a><span>, </span>
<a href="Brasilia">Brasilia</a>
```

Now, there is no empty span at the end.

Comment: Perfect!.. Thank you very much for this good solution and wonderful explanations :)

Comment: But, how make href links for city.name but span only for comma ?

Comment: I added some notes to the answer @ilw

Answer (score 7):

You should look at Thymeleaf [`#strings` utility methods](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#strings). There is a set of functions to split and join different types of lists. Your code may look like ...

```
<td th:text="${#strings.listJoin(country.cityList.![name], ',')}"></td>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help, voted up. But it does not work as it does not include `th:each`

Comment: @Rosa you should wrap it on a <th:block> or something like that, this should be the accepted answer

Comment: Too late, I marked the answer 1 month ago.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA underlines in red: `'!=', '%', '&&', '(', ')', '*', '+', '+=', ',', '-', '.', '/', <, <=, '==', '>', '>=', '?', '?.', '?:', and, div, eq, ge, gt, le, lt, mod, ne, or, '||' or '}' expected, got '.'`